# get div index with same class name in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have multi div with same class name and each div have multi element(input,select and ...). Now i want to add event to input element. how to find the div index when input event run?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='item'>
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
          <input type="text" >
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
 </div>
<div class='item'>
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
          <input type="text" >
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
 </div>
  <div class='item'>
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
          <input type="text" >
          <input type="text" ng-click='test()'>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont u use ng-repeat , then you can have $index

Comment: @Nitin Varpe yes it's right but my solution for this problem is difference.

Comment: The divs (or the elements in the div, for that matter) don't even have an index to find if they're just raw html. You either need to manually add ids to your elements or use ng-repeat as Nitin suggested. I'd suggest the latter.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find the container `div` element when a user types in an `input`? If yes, you can use jQuery's `parent()` method. Otherwise, please make your desired functionality clearer.

Comment: @sdgluck when user type in an input the div that input element put into it can be recognize. example type in 5th input alert div 2 with item class name.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments on your original post, my understanding of your desired functionality is this: when a user types into an `input` element, identify the `div` element that is the `input`'s container, and `alert()` the `div` element's `class` attribute.

In order to do this, as I said in the comment on your post, you can use jQuery's `parent()` method, which will return an element's parent as a jQuery object, and then use jQuery's `attr()` method to inspect the parent's class attribute.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdgluck/qLuj4ex0/)**

**If you are using jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.container input', function() {
    var $inputElement = $(this); // `this` is the event target
    var $parentDiv = $inputElement.parent();
    var parentClassName = $parentDiv.attr('class');
    alert(parentClassName);
});
```

**If you are not using jQuery:**

```
var inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.container input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    inputElements[i].addEventListener('onkeyup', function(evt) {
        var inputElement = evt.target; // access event target using `evt.target`
        var parentDiv = inputElement.parentNode; // get the event target's parent element
        alert(parentDiv.className);
    });
}
```